# Cable Connector Identification

Tags: connector, identification, coax

I recently bought [Belkin Ultimate Surge Protector](http://www.belkin.com/in/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=481734) for protecting my modem, router and PC. I have a broadband connection from Cable provider (through modem via coaxial cable). 
Now I wish to connect modem via Belkin Surge protector.

[image]

The above connector is used to connect to my modem.

Now I wish to connect this cable to my Belkin Surge protector. Which comes with the following connectors:
[image]

I don't know name of any connectors. Please help me to find out the names so that I can buy appropriate converters for that.

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind to explain why the downvote. Connector identification is OK as a question, regardless of the intended usage from the OP.

Comment: The identification can be shortlisted to some possibilities by measuring the impedance of the cable,if you have a multimeter.A design manual for your modem may state the female connector its has for that model for coaxial-cable.

Comment: @MaMba one cannot measure wave impedance with a multimeter. (Well, maybe there is some ingenious way that it could be possible, but only with additional equipment and great difficulty.) Since there are only a finite number of RF connectors in common use, it seems perfectly reasonable to identify it through an exhaustive search. Also, consumers typically do not possess design documentation for the products they have bought or been given by a cable company.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Well ran out of edits,It cant be alone measured using multimeter you have to either use a bridge ,to match the impedance(which is not resistance),also OP is a cable client from the supplier so measuring impedance would be silly,measuring frequency response of cable will be only left option ,which in this case is imppsoible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comments could arguably just as well be an answer:

[Ignacio Vazquez-Adams](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11606/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) is correct that [the modem connector is an F connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/176479/). The connectors on the surge protector are the old British [Belling-Lee TV aerial connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_aerial_plug), as found in Europe. The surge protector is [clearly identified](http://www.belkin.com/in/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=481734) as being meant for connection to a television, not a cable modem.

The Belling-Lee connector is not used in the USA, for good reason: it does not have controlled impedance, so it is arguably not particularly suitable even for its typical application. It can reasonably be used for radios, but at the higher transmission frequencies used for television signals, reflections from the connector are a problem. Thus, the F connector is often used where this matters to the application, such as for cable and satellite TV.

The presence of the Belling-Lee connector on the surge protector suggests that it probably also does not have controlled impedance, and its RF characteristics are likely poor in general. You can try connecting the modem to it, but the latter will probably not work as it should (if at all) if you do so.

If I were you, I would not bother with surge protection for the cable modem. Buried cables are not as subject to lightning strikes as antennas, although admittedly the surge protector will have little chance of doing anything other than exploding anyway if your TV antenna is struck by lightning. If some terrible event befalls your cable modem because of a surge on the line, it is not the end of the world. The cable company will have worse problems to deal with in this situation than having to send you a new modem.

Comment: Thanks for your valued replies @oleksandr-r
Let me show you my cable setup [see this](http://i.imgur.com/Z6pQH7B.jpg). I lost me modem and router twice due to lightening strike. That's why I wish to protect my modem and router through aforesaid surge protector.

Comment: Surge protection for cable modems can be very necessary in some areas - for instance here in Central Florida where virtually no cables are buried and lightning is a daily occurrence in the summer.

Answer (score 2):

The one on the cable is an [F connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector). The one on the power bar *looks* like a [GR connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GR_connector), but I couldn't say for certain.

Comment: It's most certainly not a GR connector, those are enormous and esoteric. It's probably the RF variant of the standard cinch/RCA connector.